# How to make GtkMenuToolButton open the same menu when 'clicked' signal is emitted?

Tags: python, gtk

I am using GtkMenuToolButton and it has a button and a menu. When you click on the arrow the menu is opened. I'd like to make the button open that same menu as well. Simply emitting "show-menu" in the "clicked" callback did not work. Please help how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the menu, save a reference to it as `self.tool_button_menu` or something; then in the `clicked` callback, call

```
self.tool_button_menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, Gtk.get_current_event_time())
```

The first two `None`s are the parent menu and the parent menu item (not applicable). The second two `None`s are a positioning callback function (more on that in a minute) and data to pass to it. `0` is the mouse button if the menu was initiated by a mouse button press (but you should pass 0, because I think in your case it's either a mouse button release or a key press.) And the last parameter is the timestamp to give to the menu popup event.

Now the positioning function. It takes two parameters and returns three:

```
def positioning_function(menu, data=None):
    # ...magic...
    return x, y, push_in
```

`push_in` should be `True` if you want the menu to be repositioned so that it always fits on the screen. Seems like a good idea. You can get good values for `x` and `y` by looking at the tool button's `get_allocation()`; read the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes of that object and calculate a nice place to put the menu.

Comment: well the actual parameters to popup would be nice, as I can't seem to get them right. Also the menu needs to be below the button not in the random mouse position (think about activating the button with keyboard, not mouse). The existing snippets with popup that I found on the internet did not work with py-gi bindings and gtk3. Please elaborate =)

Comment: Ha, you caught me there. I was too lazy to look up the parameters. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's better. I went with "my solution" below =) but thanks for explaining the "magic" parameters for this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have currently ended up doing this:

- Instead of GtkMenuToolButton I have GtkToolItem with custom content
- In custom content I have GtkMenuButton
- Inside that one, I delete the default GtkArrow and replace it with 1x2 GtkGrid which has a Label + GtkArrow

As a whole it does what I want =)